# My lineart sucks no matter what app/brush/brush settings I use

Tags: line-art

https://prnt.sc/6ReXP5NhGoUP
Here in the link is my lineart. I know it looks clean, but it looks nothing like this one: https://celcliptipsprod.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/tips_article_body/3f3c/945184/5352eb7109910ae79950d3f22a57adb3
How can I change that? I use Krita the last version, and I use a wacom tablet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the second link is clearly using much thinner multiple strokes and blurring the underlying strokes. Not sure I'd call it "cleaner".

Comment: This tutorial https://tips.clip-studio.com/en-us/articles/3800 is made around your linked goal image. Have you already tried what it suggests?